ActiveRecord query for unassociated has_many through records
The goal: I want to return all the players who are NOT members of a team.
The challenge: I need the results scoped to an individual league/season. My application supports multiple leagues and seasons. So the query must include a player that IS on a team for a different league/season, but exclude any player that is on a team that belongs to the relevant Season instance.
In the spec below, I create two users/players. I assign one to a team of the relevant season. The other is not associated with a team. The spec was passing before I added an additional team to the season. With this additional record, the query returns BOTH users.
What am I doing wrong?
The query
(This is NOT quite working yet)
class Season < ApplicationRecord

 ...

  def no_team_players
    players
      .joins("LEFT JOIN teams ON teams.season_id = #{id}")
      .joins(
        'LEFT JOIN team_memberships ON users.id = team_memberships.user_id AND teams.id = team_memberships.team_id'
      )
      .where('team_memberships.user_id IS NULL')
      .distinct
  end


The failing spec
  describe '#no_team_players' do
    let(:team_player) { FactoryBot.create(:user, email: 'team_player@gmail.com') }
    let(:no_team_player) { FactoryBot.create(:user, email: 'no_team_player@gmail.com') }
    let(:season) { FactoryBot.create(:season) }
    let(:team_player_enrollment) { FactoryBot.create(:enrollment, user: team_player, season:) }
    let(:no_team_player_enrollment) do
      FactoryBot.create(:enrollment, user: no_team_player, season:)
    end
    let(:team) { FactoryBot.create(:team, season:) }
    let(:team_membership) { FactoryBot.create(:team_membership, user: team_player, team:) }

    it 'returns the players for the season that do not have a team membership for that specific season' do
      team_player_enrollment
      no_team_player_enrollment # enrolled in the season but not on a team
      team
      team_membership

      # The following is necessary to make sure that a user can be on a team for a different season
      # and still be considered a player without a team for the current season.
      # Here we create a different season and a team for that season and add the no_team_player to that team.
      different_season = FactoryBot.create(:season)
      FactoryBot.create(:enrollment, user: no_team_player, season: different_season)
      different_season_team = FactoryBot.create(:team, season: different_season)
      FactoryBot.create(:team_membership, user: no_team_player, team: different_season_team)

      # THE SPEC PASSES IF THIS IS REMOVED
      # another team in this season
      FactoryBot.create(:team, season:)

      expect(season.no_team_players).to eq([no_team_player])
    end
  end

Right now the method is return BOTH User records (team_player and no_team_player).
Details
ruby '3.2.2'
gem 'rails', '~> 7.1.2'


I think it was useful to see your models' associations, should not have deleted it

Sorry I thought it was making the question too messy… I’ll see about reverting the edit.

My specs pass with this version of the query:
players.where.not(id: teams.joins(:team_memberships).select('team_memberships.user_id'))


Use .select('team_memberships.user_id') instead of pluck so that ActiveRecord can make a subquery instead of two queries. pluck should only be used if what you want actually is just an array of raw values.

Is this supposed to be an answer to your original question or a follow-up question? If it's a follow-up question, then it really should be a separate question rather than an answer.

@EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine I posted my answer because it technically solves my original problem. But I didn't accept it because I don't feel confident that it's the best answer. (Max already suggested an improvement.)

@max I think your suggestion to use .select should be the answer. If you submit it I'll accept.

You can just edit your answer. I already have thousands of answers.

I believe the problem in your query is that you LEFT JOIN teams, this creates more combinations of users, teams and team memberships than you want and in result even the player that has membership in the season's team will have team_memberships.user_id equal to NULL (for the second team combination that you created).
The task would be much simpler if you cached season_id reference on the team_membership table (I mean add session_id foreign key on that table as well and set it from the team upon creation).
This way you could write that query like this:
players
  # 1. Select only users that are enrolled for the season:
  .joins("INNER JOIN enrollments e ON e.user_id = users.id AND e.season_id = #{id}")
  # 2. Left join team memberships for these users and the season:
  .joins("LEFT JOIN team_memberships tm ON tm.user_id = users.id AND tm.session_id = #{id}")
  # 3. Then filter users that don't have team membership:
  .where("team_memberships.user_id IS NULL")

If you don't add session_id to team_memberships then it will be more problematic to only filter team memberships for that season. You could achieve it by adding sub-query to filter by team IDs that belong to the seasion:
# This is how step 2. from above example can look:
.joins("LEFT JOIN team_memberships tm ON tm.user_id = users.id AND tm.team_id IN (SELECT id from teams where season_id = #{id})")


In any case I don't see a problem in executing more than 1 query, it might be even more performant than having several joins. It's just better to benchmark which query (or group of queries) performs best for your task.

Thanks! I thought about adding the additional foreign key to solve this. But I generally prefer not to have two “competing” foreign keys to the same parent record. It feels a little brittle / smelly… but it would certainly make this operation simpler. Maybe it’s worth the trade off.
